# Amazon Connect: How to record outbound calls

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect, call-recording

I am trying to set outbound call recordings for my Amazon Connect contact centre but am unsure in which part of the flow to add the `Set call recording behaviour`. I have attached my contact flow if someone can please point out where exactly I need to add that particular block. I have it just before the `Transfer to queue` block but it still does not record the callback.

[image: Outbound Call Flow]

Answer (score 1):

Because the callback is a separate outbound contact, although it has the attributes of the previous inbound contact, you need to set the call recording behavior explicitly for that contact. You can do this by using the outbound whisper flow for the agent. This will get triggered when the outbound callback contact is accepted by the selected agent.

Please be aware that If you add recoding behavior to the outbound whisper flow, it would apply for outbound callbacks or manually dialed outbound call from the CCP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set it up at the Default Outbound contact flow

[Default outbound contact flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxzMJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should set an attribute of recording as true.
[image]